# Joining 2 variables to form a new variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

Firstly, I'm using jQuery, PHP, SQL, HTML and CSS.

I have a party list with 4 members. When I access my party detail page I want it to display the 4 members details with listview.

When I open the party detail page, I send a `$.post` request to my PHP to retrieve the members details from my database.

I then store them in an array in PHP and echo the response:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$mem1 = $row["mem1"];
$mem2 = $row["mem2"];
$mem3 = $row["mem3"];
$mem4 = $row["mem4"];

$result2 = json_encode(array(
    "mem1" => $mem1, 
    "mem2" => $mem2, 
    "mem3" => $mem3, 
    "mem4" => $mem4
)); 

echo $result2;
```

Next, I when I go back to my .js file to try and append the result, I can can do that only by calling out one member data. But I want to call 4 of them so i used while loop:

```
$.post("retrieveDetails.php", 
{
    teamID:teamID, // data to pass into php                     
},

function(response)
{
    console.log(response.mem1 + " " + response.mem2 + " " + response.mem3 + " " + response.mem4);

    var x = 1;
    while(x <= 4){

        // part i'm stuck at
        member = response.mem + x; 

        // if member column is not empty
        if(member != ""){ 
            $("#listview").append('<li> <img src="images/displaypic.jpg"> <h2>'+ member + '</h2> </li>').listview("refresh");
            console.log("current addee is " + member);
        }   
        x++;                                
    }                               
}, 'json'

);
```

I am doing something wrong with `member = response.mem + x;`

My ultimate result needs to be `member = response.mem1`, and after the next loop it will become `member = response.mem2` and so on.. 
But when I output it via `console.log` it returns "NaN".

Can somebody advise on a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
member = response.mem + x;
```

with

```
member = response['mem' + x];
```

Your final code should look like,

```
$.post("retrieveDetails.php", {
    teamID: teamID, // data to pass into php                     
  }, // data to pass into php

  function(response) {
    console.log(response.mem1 + " " + response.mem2 + " " + response.mem3 + " " + response.mem4);

    var x = 1, member = null;//note that, i declared member
    while (x <= 4) {
      member = response['mem' + x];
      if (member != "") { // if member column is not empty
        $("#listview").append('<li> <img src="images/displaypic.jpg"> <h2>' + member + '</h2> </li>').listview("refresh");
        console.log("current addee is " + member);
      }
      x++;
    }
  }, 'json'
);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, like this:

```
member = response["mem" + x];
```

In JavaScript, you can use either dot notation with a literal (`obj.foo`), or bracketed notation with a string (`obj["foo"]`). In the latter case, the string can be the result of any expression.

But I'd probably send back the data as an array rather than as an object:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$mem1 = $row["mem1"];
$mem2 = $row["mem2"];
$mem3 = $row["mem3"];
$mem4 = $row["mem4"];

$result2 = json_encode(array($mem1,$mem2,$mem3,$mem4));
echo $result2;
```

Then you could just index into it as `response[x]` where `x` is `0` to `3`.